# Failed to deploy application: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I can't deploy a new version on Elastic Beanstalk.

Everything was working fine until I tried to deploy a new version where I have lots of issues (It is not the first time I deploy a new version on this environment, I already have deployed dozens). When I manage to fixe all of them I got those errors:

- `Failed to deploy application.`
- `During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.`
- `Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-...'. Aborting the operation`

I redeploy the version which does not work.

Here is the Elastic Beanstalk console:

[Elastic Beanstalk console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afRgQ.png)

[Elastic Beanstalk events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIlVc.png)

The request logs button from Elastic Beanstalk return nothing.
The system log from EC2 instance shows the last working version logs.

I enable the CloudWatch logs from `Configuration` navigation pane. It added 4 files to CloudWatch logs:

- `/var/log/eb-activity.log`  -> empty so far
- `/var/log/httpd/access_log` -> empty so far
- `/var/log/httpd/error_log` -> empty so far
- `/environment-health.log` ->  `Command is executing on all instances (56 minutes or more elapsed).", "Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version \"prod-v1.7.28-0\" (deployment 128).`

It is an Amazon Linux, t2.medium instance with Apache as web server

What I already try:

- Change the name of .zip each time to be different of other zip already deploy
- Terminate the instance and the loadBalancer automatically create a new one
- Reboot the instance
- Rebuild Elastic Beanstalk environment
- Deploy a simplest code

I tried to deploy just a zip with the code below but I got same errors.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is an example paragraph. Anything in the <strong>body</strong> tag will appear on the page, just like this <strong>p</strong> tag and its contents.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

It always go back to last working version and when I tried to deploy the new version it does not work.

On some post I see some people telling it is maybe because the instance is too small but before it was working perfectly and the size does not change since then.

If you have some questions or ideas I will be very thankful.
Have a nice day !

**Answer:**
The issue was in the logs like you said. I had to ssh into my EC2 instance to reached them. The error was in the file `cfn-init-cmd.log`.
One of the command was waiting for an input so it timed out with no error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the logs of the EBS for any hints as to what goes wrong with your deployment. The AWS console
can be helpful for that.

[image]

There are also the logs that can be acquired from EC2:

[image]

CloudWatch logs is another thing to check.

[image]

You should also check the autoscaling group, and see if there are any health checks there. What kind of checks are these? What's the grace period?

Here's a list of reasons that an EC2 health check could fail.
You could launch a better ec2 instance for troubleshooting.

Instance status checks.

The following are examples of problems that can cause instance status checks to fail:

Failed system status checks

Incorrect networking or startup configuration

Exhausted memory

Corrupted file system

Incompatible kernel

Also rebuilding is really a drastic step as it destroys and rebuilds all your resources. Your ELB DNS for example will be gone, any associated EIP will be released. These things can't be reclaimed.

Comment: Yes I experienced the "bad effects" of rebuilding environment. I will not do this mistake again ^^. The logs request does not work on EBS console. And by using ssh to see directly on the server I don't know if it comes from the failing uploads or the last working version uploads. The `eb-engine.log` does not exist at least in `/var/log`

Comment: About auto scaling group the only health check is `Health check type: EC2` and the grace period `Health check grace period: 0`. I don't know anything about it I am not the one who created the auto scaling group sorry.

Comment: Are cloudwatch logs enabled? What about the events in ebs any clue there? What's the health of ebs? Gray,red,orange or green?

Comment: No cloudwatch logs are not enabled. The health is degraded. And the events are the errors I post with the question. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Just added a screen shot of the EBS console. Request logs button is disabled? Returns nothing?

Comment: In addition there are some logs that can acquired directly from the EC2 instance.

Comment: The request logs button returns nothing. I will look at the EC2 system log

Comment: I add CloudWatch Logs but I don't know witch files to watch. There is a lot in /var/log

Comment: Well, depending on yr setup, there should be health, eb activity, web server, and yr application. It would not hurt to check all of them.  I added a screen shot. You might a have different set of files.

Comment: Try deploying yr app, and then the check most recent events in Cloudwatch for errors.

Comment: In addition pls check the reasons that an ec2 health check could fail. (Updated answer)

Comment: When you say a better ec2 instance you mean a bigger one ?

Comment: Yes. I wonder if a hello app would work if deployed in this env..

Comment: ..and the deployment of  that hello app failed with the same error?

Comment: Yes, sorry I add it to the question I forgot to remove my comment about it

Comment: What I would do, is create a new elastic bean stalk env, and try the hello app, then the real app and see if there are any issues, If there are no issues I would try to see what are the differences between the old and new app. Or (if possible) I would keep the new env. Also if you have aws support, then you should use it.

Comment: I try a hello app with a new eb env and it works. Then I deploy the new app and it fails again. I will try to contact the support.

Comment: so it's something with the app, There must be an indication somewhere in the logs that's overlooked...

Comment: The instance gets terminated pretty fast so you'll find nothing in the EBS instance logs, but it's strange there's nothing in cloudwatch. Are you sure you are checking the CloudWatch console?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue and deleted the wrong application versions. And increased the command timeout.

Default max deployment time -Command timeout- is 600 (10 minutes)

Go to Your Environment → Configuration → Deployment preferences → Command timeout

Increase the Deployment preferences higher like 1800 and then try to deploy the previous working application version. It will work.